# Redirect and change URL with Apache/htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change/redirect URIs with http/https in this way:

> from: `http:// or https://xyz.lastdomain.com/b/custom/any-string/456?foo=bar`

> to: `https://custom.nextdomain.com/b/any-string/456?foo=bar`

the custom string should be in the new URL and everything from b so as the end of the URI should be appended.

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Need more clarity. Are there more than one subdomains that you want to redirect? Is `custom.nextdomain.com` already defined in `VistualHost`?

Comment: Thank you for your question, I try to explain this: the first URL will be called from a different (old) webserver, where "custom" acts as a placeholder.

The second URL is on the new server with a different url-scheme, where "custom" should be applied with the same value as in the original URL and everything from "b" on should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ma try this redirect rule from old site's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.lastdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^b/([\w-]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.nextdomain.com/b/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

This assumes all the paths start with `/b/` right after the domain name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This solution sets the start, but is not ready yet. It leads to the output "http://custom.nextdomain.com/custom?foo=bar". The "custom" after the "/" should not be there, but instead the "b/any-string/456?foo=bar".

Comment: Oh sorry there was a typo, please try my updated answer

Comment: This is great and it works now, thank you very much. Unfortunately I made a mistake within my question. The "/b/" is not AFTER the "custom", it is always before the "custom", right after the ".com/". I'm terribly sorry for that, do you know how to adapt this, so that it works under the new conditions? (I edited the original post)

Comment: Not a problem, we all make mistakes. Please try my updated answer.

Comment: the "/b/" gets now removed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224977/discussion-between-philg-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, considering that your htaccess file and custom folder are in root location.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !custom [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://custom.nextdomain.com/custom/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the condition was not met :(

Comment: @PhilG, any error you are getting in logs? Or please elaborate more what's not working